# Instalacion de Docker para Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hola he tratado de installar Docker en Windows pero siempre que trado de iniciarlo me sale error "Hyper-V feature is not enabled." Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

Comment: si tu procesador lo soporta, fijate por aquí https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Comment: Tienes instalado el programa de virtualizacion de Microsoft **HYper-V**?, revisa si se esta ejecutando dentro de los procesos

Comment: @aloMalbarez Mi Procesador si lo soporta

Comment: @SebastianSalazar No lo tengo Instalado, Lo intente y me da un error

Comment: Recuerda que **Docker** se encarga de virtualizar aplicaciones como un servidor web, servidor FTP, tambien puedes hacer uso de Virtual Box, al finalizar la instalación, te indicará que es recomendable hacer uso de Hyper-V, pero igual puedes hacerlo con VB

Comment: @SebastianSalazar entonces podria usar Virtual Box para correguir el error de Docker ?

Comment: Si puedes hacer uso de **Docker** usando VirtualBox recuerda tener la virtualizacion activada en tu sistema operativo

Comment: en mi experiencia es mejor montar una VM linux y usar docker ahí, a windows le cuesta un poco el asunto

Comment: abajo una referencia para iniciar hiper-V, lo probe en windows 8 64 y funciono. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Comment: Asegúrate de no estar usando Windows Home, ya que en esta versión no se puede instalar/activar Hyper-V. De modo contrario este enlace te puede ayudar https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v.